# Using Google-Account to log in

Tags: php, authentication, google-account

i develop a php-site with user-accounts. to register easier i want to offer the user to (alternativly) log in via they´re google-account (like here on stackoverflow).

how to connect the google-account with my site?

Answer (score 2):

Sign in with Google account using OAuth2.0 which is clearly explained

http://www.idiotminds.com/sign-in-with-google-account-using-oauth2-0/