# Gmail Login on My Website & Varifying Users' Email Ids

Tags: php, authentication, gmail

I want to have gmail login for users on my web portal. In addition, I want to store their email ids and check them to allow them to alter data in the portal. (i.e. Only users with email ids with @mycollege.ac.in will be allowed). And only the user who has filled up a form to input his data, will be able to modify or remove it.)

I want to have gmail login so it becomes easy for users. Also, if user is already logged in with gmail, he will be directly allowed to input data on the portal.

I have spent much time trying to google how to do this and I have only gotten as far as having a gmail login button on the site with openid. Nothing about storing the email id or automatically logging in. Also, the code of those pages is very difficult to understand for me.

I am new in PHP. I only have basic knowledge of MySQL and PHP. So can anyone please explain how to do or what to use? Or perhaps some link to a page that explains it simply?
( I have already visited 
    https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?csw=1
but still I am stuck.)

Comment: Take a look to these answers..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709992/using-google-account-to-log-in

Comment: All these answers explain about creating gmail login button with google api. But I specifically need user ids for varification. And none of the links explain the code of the php files used in that. Even if I could understand the code, I might be able to modify it for my use. Can I please get a simple and useful answer or link with explaination?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something like this -> http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-google-account-oauth_231.html

On this example, they do a login with Google account and get email and image of the user profile..

I didn't test the code, it was the first result when i google about it...

Comment: It doesn't give any explanation, I was looking for some page that explains it all in great deal so I could modify it according to my needs. But will try out later.

Comment: Lol... It is giving you the email and the image of the user after successful login (source code included..) what else do you need more?

After you got the email just check with php string functions if the email contains @yourcollege.com etc.. else kick out the user..

Comment: I don't understand what to do. Created new project on google console. Downloaded the json file, then what? Please explain, I don't have much background in php.

Comment: Maybe you need to start from somewhere else..
Do you have a working website PHP & MySql driven? If yes, do you have a table for users (so you can match authenticated users via google). do you have a working user login / signup modules on your portal... if all yes than you can start the authenticate with google or Facebook or others.. If the answers are no, please create a new question targeting these missing things on your project. once you done with user functions, next step is integrating your portal with social network authentication tools.. Cheers.

Comment: i have working website PHP and MySQL driven.I don't have table of users and I don't need one. I am planning to check users email id domain to make sure he is allowed. And do I need to have a seperate login/signup module? Can't I directly work with gmail login?