# Log in using Google and Facebook accounts

Tags: jsf-2, google-oauth, jsf-2.2, facebook-authentication, google-oauth-java-client

In a similar [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709992/using-google-account-to-log-in), I tried to access the [API](https://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) but the link is broken, My problem is that in my JSF page I want to put two buttons, links or another way to let users register using their accounts on `google` or `facebook`, I know there is some kind of a web service but what am I going to save for each user in my database after the registration, is there a return value?, please help me out.

Comment: Please, tell us what you have tried, why it does not work and how.

Comment: The link to google in the answer is not working, I'm still searching the internet, this is the [link](https://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) for google(), what about facebook?

Comment: I found the correct [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login), downloaded a JSON file after I created a client for my web application on google developers console, but I don't know what to do with that JSON file, code: '{"web":{"auth_uri":"https..","client_secret":"..","token_uri":"..","client_email":"..","client_x509_cert_url":"https..","client_id":"..","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis..."}}'